# How can I create a URL that links to a button press with query parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, url

I am trying to create a special URL at the following website:
https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abq3970

Basically, I want a link where on-load, the "+3 authors" button is automatically pressed, so all authors are visible on the page without any user input. I was thinking this may be possible with query parameters at the end of the URL:
e.g. [https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abq3970?data-action="reveal"](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abq3970?data-action=%22reveal%22)

Is this possible? Appreciate the advice!

I tried looking through the elements and I found whether or not they're hidden depends on the size of the window (sm, md, or lg), and a variable for each name: data-displayed-on. However, I don't know if I can modify these with query parameters.

Comment: Have you tired setting the `data-hidden-on` data attributes to `none` using a page load event? Right now, by default, just by looking at the buttons toggling modes whne pressed, those span tags data attributes are set => `data-hidden-on="sm md lg"` so when you load and the page is small, medium or large those are hidden by default, at least this is what I assume without digging into the JS logic that has to do with the dataset attributes. Do you not have access to JS with this site?

Comment: Only the site owner could offer the functionality you ask for with the URL parameter. You can however write a tampermonkey userscript to manipulate the DOM of a website based on your needs.

Comment: @dalelandry I don't have access to the JS code; it's a private website, not mine. Is there any way I could append this page load event into the URL? The use-case is sharing a URL with someone and it loads a page with the button already pressed (i.e. all the authors are shown regardless of window size)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because this is the site's internal functionality (most likely achieved via JavaScript code). However you can use the URL https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abq3970?cookieSet=1#tab-contributors, which would open the side bar (just paste this into a new browser tab: if you are already on the article, this doesn't seem to work).

Essentially you you need to append "#tab-contributors" to the original URL.

Comment: I found that #tab-contributors header as well, just wasn't quite what I was looking for; thanks for looking though